# angular.js - passing an object from directive to the view controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

***Please note: there is a Plunker link:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/PAINmQUHSjgPTkXoYAxf?p=preview

At first I wanted to pass an object as parameter on directive click event,
(it was too complex for me), so i decide to simplify it by sending the event and the object separately.

In my program the object is always undefined in the view-controller and the view itself in oppose to the Plunker example.

In the Plunker example it's undefined on the controller only on the first passing event (the second directive click event works fine).

- I don't know why I get 2 different results in the simple Plunker simulation and my massive code, I hope both cases are 2 different results of the same logic issue.
- A solution with passing an object as parameter from directive by event function will be welcome as well.

**HTML**

```
<pick-er get-obj-d="getObj()" obj-d="obj"></pick-er>
```

**View-Controller**

```
function mainController($scope)
{
    $scope.test = "work";
    $scope.getObj = function(){
        $scope.test = $scope.obj;
    }
}
```

**Directive:**

```
function PickerDirective()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: // isolated scope
        {
            obj : '=objD',
            getObj: '&getObjD'
        }, 
        controller: DirectiveController,
        template:`<div ng-repeat="item in many">
                      <button ng-click="sendObj()">
                          Click on me to send Object {{item.num}}
                      </button>
                  </div>`
    };


    function DirectiveController($scope, $element)
    {
        $scope.many =[{"num":1,}];
        $scope.sendObj = function() {
            $scope.obj = {"a":1,"b":2, "c":3};
            $scope.getObj();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I your case, will be more simple to use events, take a look at this Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/bFYDfhTqaUo8xhzSz0qH?p=preview

**Main controller**

```
function mainController($scope)
{
console.log("mainCTRL ran")
$scope.test = "work";
  $scope.$on('newObj', function (event, obj) {
    $scope.obj = obj;
    $scope.test = obj;
  });
}
```

**Directive controller**

```
function DirectiveController($scope, $element)
    {
     $scope.many =[{"num":1,}]
        $scope.sendObj = function() {
          $scope.$emit('newObj', {"a":1,"b":2, "c":3} )
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: DirectiveController,
        template:'<div ng-repeat="item in many"><button ng-click="sendObj()">Click on me to send Object {{item.num}}</button></div>' 
    }
```

Comment: Can u please tell me what is the usage of "event" inside the $on, i couldn't find any solid answer on the net beside some philosophic definitions.  a link or example will be accepted as well :-)

Comment: did you check angular documentation? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope, 'event' is the event object passed by angular to the callback